# Looker data studio - Extract text after character (row table)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, looker-studio, google-analytics-4, calculated-field

i have a cd_sku custom dimension of a non- standard GA4 ecommerce events , i want to extract each cd_sku as a single value in a row but i don't know how to do it, could you guys please help to split value by " | " to make more rows out of one.

the dimension value were separate by'|' and depends on events they can be up to 5 '|' in a value, example:
row 1: US-SUE-ODD-UPH-LM-KALTH/NUT | SODE-ELKSIE-LG-TWH/ASTH |

row 2: OH-VIT-MET-OCC-ETTAN | CH-LACH-ARM-TAN |

row 3: SWT-VOPL-TIUM-PUT

row 4: OH-SKUE-POI-UPH-LMLTH/LP

, I want them to split them like this:

row 1:US-SUE-ODD-UPH-LM-KALTH/NUT

row 2:SODE-ELKSIE-LG-TWH/ASTH

row 3:OH-VIT-MET-OCC-ETTAN

row 4:CH-LACH-ARM-TAN

row 5:SWT-VOPL-TIUM-PUT

row 6:OH-SKUE-POI-UPH-LMLTH/LP